# Does Spring Boot Support Multiple Content Negotiation Strategies Base On URL Pattern

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Our Spring Boot webapp consists of a couple of URL strategies. The /api URL's are for REST services and content negotiation is consistent with best practices (headers or request parameters). The /web URLS are for a legacy Freemarker application which uses URL extensions for mapping content type (.html, .json, etc). A recent change by Spring has caused the problem (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24179).

The content negotiation for the two URL's are different and I was wondering if we could define multiple content negotiation strategies...using URL's to select between them.